# angular button appears twice why?

Tags: angular

I have a little problem with angular: when I access the localhost page, the "prenota" button appears twice, could you help me understand why it appears twice?

The final result that I would like to have is to have a "prenota" button (first component) - click - second component with button go back. On click I would like the "prenota" button to appear.

HTML file with the first component with `ngIF`

```
<a class="butLink" mat-raised-button *ngIf="this.isButtonVisible" (click)="this.isButtonVisible = false" routerLink="prenotazioni" >Prenota</a>
```

*app-routing.module.ts*

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'prenotazioni', component: PrenotazioniComponent },
  { path: '', component: PrenotaComponent },
];
```

Second component with back button

```
<a class="butLink" mat-raised-button routerLink="" >Indietro</a>
```

Comment: can you provide a stackblitz? or more of what your html looks like? The code that you have provided is valid

Comment: remove `this` keyword from your ngIf condition. replace `*ngIf="this.isButtonVisible"` with `*ngIf="isButtonVisible"`.and also remove this keyword from click as well.

Comment: thanks for the advice, however the situation remains the same, when I click on the back button the ngif remains in false! but I no longer have the double button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code as below.

```
<a class="butLink" mat-raised-button *ngIf="isButtonVisible" (click)="isButtonVisible = false" routerLink="prenotazioni" >Prenota</a>
```

Comment: thank you but the problem rest the same, when i click on back button the "prenota" button rest invisible :/